# How to make table-cell borders stick together in css?

Tags: css, xml, browser

I am making a little project for my study class. It's a xml+css page. In the css file I included table, 3xtable-cells, and a lot of table-rows. I can't figure out how to make "table-cells borders to stick together". Could you help me?

XML file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Sklep SYSTEM "Sklep.dtd" >
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="Sklep.css"?>


<Sklep>

    <ListaProduktów> 

        <Produkt IdProduktu="1111" Kategoria="Napoje" Producent="Cola Company"> 
            <Nazwa>Coca-Cola 2L</Nazwa> 
            <Kalorie>2000kcal</Kalorie>
        </Produkt>
        <Produkt IdProduktu="1112" Kategoria="Napoje" Producent="Tymbark">
            <Nazwa>Napój jabłkowy 1L</Nazwa>
            <Kalorie>1000kcal</Kalorie>
        </Produkt>
        <Produkt IdProduktu="1113" Kategoria="Nabiał" Producent="Nabiałex">
            <Nazwa>Serek wiejski z twarożkiem</Nazwa>
            <Kalorie>300kcal</Kalorie>
        </Produkt>
        <Produkt IdProduktu="1114" Kategoria="Nabiał" Producent="Danone">
            <Nazwa>Fantazja truskawkowa</Nazwa>
            <Kalorie>200kcal</Kalorie>
        </Produkt>
        <Produkt IdProduktu="1115" Kategoria="Nabiał" Producent="Serex">
            <Nazwa>Ser żółty pół tłusty 1kg</Nazwa>
            <Kalorie>4000kcal</Kalorie>
        </Produkt>
        <Produkt IdProduktu="1116" Kategoria="Alkohol" Producent="Polmos">
            <Nazwa>Wódka żytniówka 0,5L</Nazwa>
            <Kalorie>500kcal</Kalorie>
        </Produkt>
        <Produkt IdProduktu="1117" Kategoria="Alkohol" Producent="Jack Daniels">
            <Nazwa>Whisky Jack Daniels 1L</Nazwa>
            <Kalorie>2000kcal</Kalorie>
        </Produkt>
        <Produkt IdProduktu="1118" Kategoria="Mięso" Producent="Morliny">
            <Nazwa>Parówki śmieszki 5szt.</Nazwa>
            <Kalorie>120kcal</Kalorie>
        </Produkt>
        <Produkt IdProduktu="1119" Kategoria="Mięso" Producent="Wędlinex">
            <Nazwa>Wędlina z kurczaka 200g</Nazwa>
            <Kalorie>340kcal</Kalorie>
        </Produkt>
        <Produkt IdProduktu="1120" Kategoria="Mięso" Producent="Schabex">
            <Nazwa>Kiełbasa krakowska 400g</Nazwa>
            <Kalorie>700kcal</Kalorie>
        </Produkt>
        <Produkt IdProduktu="1121" Kategoria="Przekąski" Producent="Crunchips">
            <Nazwa>Chipsy Crunchips 120g</Nazwa>
            <Kalorie>3000kcal</Kalorie>
        </Produkt>
        <Produkt IdProduktu="1122" Kategoria="Przekąski" Producent="Chrupex">
            <Nazwa>Paluszki solone 200g</Nazwa>
            <Kalorie>250kcal</Kalorie>
        </Produkt>
        <Produkt IdProduktu="1123" Kategoria="Słodycze" Producent="Wedel">
            <Nazwa>Czekolada Wedel 120g</Nazwa>
            <Kalorie>1000kcal</Kalorie>
        </Produkt>
        <Produkt IdProduktu="1124" Kategoria="Słodycze" Producent="SłodkiMiś">
            <Nazwa>Ciastka Kruchy Miś 300g</Nazwa>
            <Kalorie>1200kcal</Kalorie>
        </Produkt>

    </ListaProduktów>

    <Klienci>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="marcin_kiełbasa">
            <Imię>Marcin</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Kiełbasa</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="ania_wolna">
            <Imię>Ania</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Wolna</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="bill_szybki">
            <Imię>Bill</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Szybki</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="maria_jopek">
            <Imię>Maria</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Jopek</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="wojciech_szczęsny">
            <Imię>Wojciech</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Szczęsny</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="kuba_kasza">
            <Imię>Kuba</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Kasza</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="antoni_macierewicz">
            <Imię>Antoni</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Macierewicz</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="andrzej_duda">
            <Imię>Andrzej</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Duda</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="piotr_marzec">
            <Imię>Piotr</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Marzec</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="kajtek_chudy">
            <Imię>Kajtek</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Chudy</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="tomasz_yamaha">
            <Imię>Tomasz</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Yamaha</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="kamila_słodka">
            <Imię>Kamila</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Słodka</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="michał_cienias">
            <Imię>Michał</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Cienias</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="joanna_krupa">
            <Imię>Joanna</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Krupa</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="jarek_koza">
            <Imię>Jarek</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Koza</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="ola_stodoła">
            <Imię>Ola</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Stodoła</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="ryszard_kozioł">
            <Imię>Ryszard</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Kozioł</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
        <Osoba IdOsoby="andrzej_spokojny">
            <Imię>Andrzej</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>Spokojny</Nazwisko>
        </Osoba>
    </Klienci>



    <ListaZakupów>
        <Zakup IdOsoby="marcin_kiełbasa" IdProduktu="1111">
          <DataZakupu Dzień="10" Miesiąc="12" Rok="2016" />
          <Płatność rodzaj="gotówka"/>
          <Wartość Waluta="PLN">5.00</Wartość>
        </Zakup>
        <Zakup IdOsoby="ania_wolna" IdProduktu="1112">
          <DataZakupu Dzień="12" Miesiąc="12" Rok="2016" />
          <Płatność rodzaj="gotówka"/>
          <Wartość Waluta="PLN">8.00</Wartość>
        </Zakup>
        <Zakup IdOsoby="andrzej_duda" IdProduktu="1113">
          <DataZakupu Dzień="08" Miesiąc="12" Rok="2016" />
          <Płatność rodzaj="gotówka"/>
          <Wartość Waluta="USD">4.00</Wartość>
        </Zakup>
        <Zakup IdOsoby="andrzej_spokojny" IdProduktu="1114">
          <DataZakupu Dzień="10" Miesiąc="05" Rok="2016" />
          <Płatność rodzaj="karta"/>
          <Wartość Waluta="PLN">5.00</Wartość>
        </Zakup>
        <Zakup IdOsoby="joanna_krupa" IdProduktu="1115">
          <DataZakupu Dzień="10" Miesiąc="12" Rok="2016" />
          <Płatność rodzaj="gotówka"/>
          <Wartość Waluta="PLN">15.01</Wartość>
        </Zakup>
        <Zakup IdOsoby="jarek_koza" IdProduktu="1116">
          <DataZakupu Dzień="01" Miesiąc="01" Rok="2016" />
          <Płatność rodzaj="karta"/>
          <Wartość Waluta="PLN">9.20</Wartość>
        </Zakup>
        <Zakup IdOsoby="kajtek_chudy" IdProduktu="1117">
          <DataZakupu Dzień="17" Miesiąc="04" Rok="2016" />
          <Płatność rodzaj="gotówka"/>
          <Wartość Waluta="PLN">3.00</Wartość>
        </Zakup>
        <Zakup IdOsoby="kamila_słodka" IdProduktu="1120">
          <DataZakupu Dzień="01" Miesiąc="09" Rok="2016" />
          <Płatność rodzaj="karta"/>
          <Wartość Waluta="EUR">3.19</Wartość>
        </Zakup>
        <Zakup IdOsoby="michał_cienias" IdProduktu="1122">
          <DataZakupu Dzień="15" Miesiąc="07" Rok="2016" />
          <Płatność rodzaj="gotówka"/>
          <Wartość Waluta="PLN">10.99</Wartość>
        </Zakup>
        <Zakup IdOsoby="ola_stodoła" IdProduktu="1123">
          <DataZakupu Dzień="22" Miesiąc="11" Rok="2016" />
          <Płatność rodzaj="karta"/>
          <Wartość Waluta="USD">11.00</Wartość>
        </Zakup>

    </ListaZakupów>

    <Autorzy>
        <Autor Indeks="195603">
            <Imię>dfgdfgdfg</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>dfgdfgdfg</Nazwisko>
        </Autor>
        <Autor Indeks="195626">
            <Imię>dfgdfgdfg</Imię>
            <Nazwisko>gdfgdfgdfg</Nazwisko>
        </Autor>
    </Autorzy>

    <Poprawki>
        <Poprawka Indeks="195626">
            <Data>10-10-2016</Data>
        </Poprawka>
    </Poprawki>


</Sklep>
```

CSS file :

```css
Sklep
{
    /*margin: 10px; */
    display:table;
    background-color: #FFA500;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: "Arial";
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:100%;

}

ListaProduktów, Klienci, ListaZakupów
{
    display: table-cell;

}

Klienci:before
{
    /*margin-left: 5px;*/
    display: block;
    content: "Klienci";
    font-family: Verdana;
    background-color: rgb(239, 197, 19);
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
     /*width:205px;*/
    border: 2px solid red;


}

ListaProduktów:before
{
    /*margin-left: 5px;*/
    display: block;
    content: "Produkty";
    font-family: Verdana;
    background-color: rgb(255, 98, 0);
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    /* width:202px;*/
    border: 2px solid red;

}

ListaZakupów:before
{
    /*margin-left: 5px;*/
    display: block;
    content: "Zakupy";
    font-family: Verdana;
    background-color: rgb(183, 82, 19);
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    /*width:253px;*/
    border: 2px solid red;

}

Produkt
{
    display: table-row;
    /*height: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 5px;


    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;*/

    border: 3px dotted red;
    border-radius: 2px;


}

Produkt:hover
{
    background-color: rgb(255, 98, 0);
    border-style: double;
}

Produkt > Nazwa
{
    display: block;
    /*height: 25px;*/
    font-weight: bold;
   /* margin-bottom: 10px;*/
    text-align: left;
}

Produkt > Kalorie
{
    display:block;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

Kalorie:before
{
    content: "kalorie: ";
}

Produkt:after
{
    margin-top: 3px;
    content: "Producent: " attr(Producent) ", Kategoria: " attr(Kategoria) " ";
    font-size: 10px;
}

Osoba
{
    display: table-row;
    /*height: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 5px;

    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;*/

    border: 3px dotted red;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

Osoba:after
{

    margin-top: auto;
    content: "Numer id: " attr(IdOsoby) "";
    font-size: 10px;
}

Osoba > Imię
{
    display: block;
   /* height: 25px;*/
    font-weight: bold;
    /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/
    text-align: left;
}

Osoba > Nazwisko
{
    display:block;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

Osoba:hover
{
background-color: rgb(239, 197, 19);
    border-style: double;
}


Zakup
{
    display: table-row;
    /*height: 80px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 5px;

    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;*/

    border: 3px dotted red;
    border-radius: 2px;

}

Zakup:hover
{
background-color: rgb(183, 82, 19);
border-style: double;
}

Zakup:before
{
display: block;

    content: ""attr(IdOsoby)" kupił produkt o id:"attr(IdProduktu)"";
    /*padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;*/
    text-align: left;

}

DataZakupu:after
{
content: "w dniu "attr(Dzień)"-"attr(Miesiąc)"-"attr(Rok)"";
text-align: left;
/*padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;*/

}

Płatność:after
{
content: "używając: "attr(rodzaj)"";
text-align: left;
/*padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;*/

}

Wartość:before
{
 content: "równowartość: "
}

Wartość[Waluta="PLN"]:after
{
    content: "PLN";
}

Wartość[Waluta="USD"]:after
{
    content: "USD";
}

Wartość[Waluta="EUR"]:after
{
    content: "EUR";
}

Autorzy, Poprawki
{
    display:table-caption;
    color: black;
    font-size:10px;
}

Autorzy:before
{
    color: black;
    font-size:10px;
    content: "Autorzy: "
}

Autorzy > Autor:after
{
    content: " [ " attr(Indeks) " ] ";
}

Poprawki:before
{
    color: black;
    font-size:10px;
    content: "Ostatnia poprawka: "
}
```

Image shows the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap up your current columns (ListaProduktów, Klienci, ListaZakupów) in table-cells and turn them into tables.

```
<Sklep>
 <Row>
  <Column>
   <ListaProduktów> ...
   </ListaProduktów>
  </Column>
  <Column>
   <Klienci> ...
   </Klienci>
  </Column>
  <Column>
   <ListaZakupów > ...
   </ListaZakupów >
  </Column>
 </Row>
</Sklep>
```

where Row is `display: table-row;` and Column is `display: table-cell;`. ListaProduktów, Klienci and ListaZakupów should change to `display: table; width: 100%;`.